# Passing workflow metadata to job template

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Is it possible to pass workflow metadata (`id`,`name`, `status` ...) to a job template? Like it is done in notification personalized messages?

Comment: Hi. Welcome here, please see [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please edit your question and add the required details.

Answer (score 0):

According Ansible Tower REST API documentation [Job Templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates) create or [`launch`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_launch_create), there seems to be no such option except of `description`.